# How to create a self extracting executable from a set of binaries?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyinstaller

I have a bunch of linux binaries (executables) and shared libraries (.so files) created using pyinstaller from a set of python applications.

```
executable1
executable2
sharedlib1.so
sharedlib2.so
...
sharedlib50.so
```

Is it possible to create a self extracting executable that extracts and copies all these files to /tmp/.. and launches from there? What application should I use for that?

Comment: Have you considered making a deb/rpm/whatever package?

Comment: No, I intend to distribute this in a shared location that is mounted for all users. The users should be able invoke the application from there. But when the invocation happens, it would be good if the application is extracted to user's temp and run from there.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701650/how-to-make-unix-binary-self-contained

Comment: This sounds like what you may be looking for: https://github.com/gammazero/pymakeself